# Masonry Item overlap in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, jquery-masonry, masonry

I try to use masonry in Angular. But I am stuck while I resize items. I used angular-masonry, ngInfinite, Jquery. 
Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/h4r4nceA725JeVBvQH7F?p=preview

HTML

```
     <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='0'>
           <div masonry="" >
           <div class="grid">
             <div class="masonry-brick grid-item" ng-repeat='image in images'>
                <p>{{image}}</p>
            </div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Angular

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['wu.masonry', 'infinite-scroll']);
  myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
   $scope.images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
      var last = $scope.images[$scope.images.length - 1];
      for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        $scope.images.push(last + i);
      }
    };
  });
```

JQuery

```
   var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: 160
    });

    $grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item', function() {
      // change size of item via class
      $( this ).toggleClass('grid-item--gigante');
      // trigger layout
      $grid.masonry();
    });
```

Can I resize the item without using jquery ?

Comment: I'm confused, your plunkr works as expected. So what is your question?

Comment: Click any grid. You see that grid will overlap on others.